# 12 x 16 two story Cottage lifting

Tags: structural

How do I lift this with three beams? I would like to put in 8 inch round pilings at the end of the beams and lift it on top of those. What can I use as beams? What size? Steel or wood? What about flitch beams

Comment: What is "This"?  Need pictures, and a sketch or drawing for starters.